# como llenar los datos en los input en html

Tags: javascript, html, axios

buenas estoy aprendiendo axios y quiero obtener los datos de un post en los input , pero no me esta llenando los datos ; al traer los datos al console.log si me muestra los datos pero esos datos los quiero mostrar en mis input ¿como lo hago? . Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
 function fnObtener(){
  var id= $('#txtId').val();
  axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/usu/obtenerUsuario', {
"ID_USUARIO": id
}, {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
}, {
}).then((response) => {
fnRespuestaObtener(response.data);;
})
}

function fnRespuestaObtener(){
  var id= $('#txtId').val();
  var nombre= $('#txtNombres').val();
  var apellido= $('#txtApellidos').val();
  var usuario= $('#txtUsuario').val();
  var contrasena= $('#txtContrasena').val();

  if(id=="ID_USUARIO"){
    nombre="nom_USUARIO",
    apellido="apell_USUARIO",
    usuario="usu_USUARIO",
    contrasena="contra_USUARIO"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- A tu funcion `fnRespuestaObtener()` tienes que pasarle como parametro la data que obtienes en `axios` por lo que tu funcion quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
function fnRespuestaObtener(data){
  
}
```

2.- En ningun momento cambias el valor de tus `inputs` solo los asignas en una variable para cambiar el valor de tus inputs tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function fnRespuestaObtener(data){
  var id = $('#txtId').val();


//AQUI TIENES QUE ACCEDER A LA DATA QUE TRAES Y LUEGO A LA INFORMACION QUE 
    DESEAS OBTENER


  if(id==data.ID_USUARIO){
    $('#txtNombres').val(data.nom_USUARIO);
    $('#txtApellidos').val(data.apell_USUARIO);
    $('#txtUsuario').val(data.usu_USUARIO);
    $('#txtContrasena').val(data.contra_USUARIO);
  }
}
```

3.- Quiero suponer que `$('#txtId').val()` ya trae un valor por defecto, de lo contrario **nunca entrará al if** prueba borrando tu if y me dices si te llena los campos o no.

4.- Otro ejemplo para poder cambiar el `value` de tus `inputs`:

```
function fnRespuestaObtener(data){
//TIENES QUE ACCEDER AL ELEMENTO - NO AL VALOR DE TUS INPUTS EJEMPLO
  var id= $('#txtId');
  var nombre= $('#txtNombres');
  var apellido= $('#txtApellidos');
  var usuario= $('#txtUsuario');
  var contrasena= $('#txtContrasena');

// VALIDAS

  if(id.val()==data.ID_USUARIO){
    nombre.val(data.nom_USUARIO);
    apellido.val(data.apell_USUARIO);
    usuario.val(data.usu_USUARIO);
    contrasena.val(data.contra_USUARIO);
  }
}
```

Comment: no me da error , pero tampoco me regresa la data en los input

Comment: en console.log(response.data); si me da los datos del usuario

Comment: Pero en tu funcion **fnRespuestaObtener** has un console.log quiero ver que llega en esa funcion